# SDL.NET runtime without installation?

Tags: sdl.net

With plain old sdl in C i would copy the dlls i need into the exe directory and was able to run without install.

Now i am using sdl.net. I tried doing that but had no luck. Not even a clue to what dlls are missing as i did in the old C way. How can i have users run my sdl app without installation?

Answer (score 0):

You might create a Setup Proyect and include the DLLs inside (I Thinks that Visual Studio inslude automacally):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19x10e5c%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

It's not posible that the users runs only the exe. The users, in that case, must install the SDL.Net reditribudible or they may install manually in GAC some DLLs!